# Trying to create a menu in python but loop won't exit

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, while-loop

Here is my code:

```
item=0
while True:
    menu=input (""" ----- Heart Attacks On A Bun ----------
          1.    The Big MOO Combo . . . . 5.99
          2.    Big MOO . . . . . . . . . 3.99
          3.    Spring Surprise . . . . . 1.99
          4.    Fries . . . . . . . . . . 1.29
          5.    Pop . . . . . . . . . . . 1.19
          6.    Exit
          ________________________________________

          What would you like? one for combo, two for Big MOO etc.
          """)
    if item=="one":
        item+=5.99
    elif item=="two":
        item+=3.99
    elif item=="three":
        item+=1.99
    elif item=="Four":
        item+=1.29
    elif item=="Five":
        item+=1.19
    elif item=="six":
        break
        print ("Your total is", item,"dollars")
```

How come when I type in six my loop doesn't exit and print the total? Also I am a beginner this is for a highschool course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with the code as you wrote it.

1. `menu` needs to be checked for input, not item(e.i. `if item==`should be `if menu==`)
2. `item=="one"` needs to be changed to `menu == 1`(Same for the rest of the comparisons) unless you expect users to type in "one" rather than pressing 1
3. `break` needs to be moved to the line after your final print statement, as it is breaking before you can print anything.

**Nitpick**: `print ("Your total is", item,"dollars")` prints a tuple, which doesn't look very nice. `print "Your total is $" + str(item)` looks much more professional.

Fixed:

```
item=0
while True:
    menu = int(input (""" ----- Heart Attacks On A Bun ----------
          1.    The Big MOO Combo . . . . 5.99
          2.    Big MOO . . . . . . . . . 3.99
          3.    Spring Surprise . . . . . 1.99
          4.    Fries . . . . . . . . . . 1.29
          5.    Pop . . . . . . . . . . . 1.19
          6.    Exit
          ________________________________________

          What would you like? one for combo, two for Big MOO etc.
          """))

    if menu == 1:
        item+=5.99
    elif menu == 2:
        item+=3.99
    elif menu == 3:
        item+=1.99
    elif menu == 4:
        item+=1.29
    elif menu == 5:
        item+=1.19
    elif menu == 6:
        print("Your total is $" + str(item))
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
item=0    
while True:

    menu =input(""" ----- Heart Attacks On A Bun ----------

          1.    The Big MOO Combo . . . . 5.99
          2.    Big MOO . . . . . . . . . 3.99
          3.    Spring Surprise . . . . . 1.99
          4.    Fries . . . . . . . . . . 1.29
          5.    Pop . . . . . . . . . . . 1.19
          6.    Exit
          ________________________________________

          What would you like? one for combo, two for Big MOO etc.
          """)

    if menu == str(1):
        item+=(5.99)
    elif menu == str(2):
        item+=3.99
    elif menu == str(3):
        item+=1.99
    elif menu == str(4):
        item+=1.29
    elif menu == str(5):
        item+=1.19
    elif menu == str(6):
        print ("Your total is", item,"dollars")
        break
```

The input could be changed to a `str` and your `break` command came before your `print` command.

Or it could be done just as David explained before me (I actually would prefer his way, as it requires the `int` input, as opposed to my conversion to `str`.)